# How to change default path/url in routes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, nested-resources

I'm working on a simple reservation application. Here are my routes

```
resources :users do
  get 'reservations', on: :member
end

resources :listings do
  resources :reservations
end
```

When I try to make a reservation, action `reservations#new` takes me to `reservations_path` . Of course I'm getting error as this path doesn't exist. I'd like action `new` to take me to `listing_reservations_path` instead. I was hopping it will be done automatically since  `resources :reservations` is in nested resources. I read about routes and tried many things but can't find any working way of doing it. Is it possible?

Comment: first check routes..  through rake routes..

Comment: what do you mean by action `reservations#new` takes you to `reservations_path`? Do you mean to say that form helper when used with controller and action as `reservation` and `new` sets the path to `reservations_path`?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be unclear on the [nature of routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). The action `reservations#new` exists independently from any route. A route is just a way to map a URL path to a controller and action. If you are trying to do something like:

```
redirect_to controller: :resources, action: :new
```

You will have trouble, as all of your routes require some context. Instead, you need to provide whatever the URL helper you're using with a context:

```
redirect_to listing_reservations_path(@listing)

link_to "New Reservation", new_listing_reservation_path(@listing)    

link_to "Reservation", [@listing, @reservation]
```